# TypeError with Django URL Regex

Tags: python, regex, django

Hi I'm always been confused with Regex, and I don't understand the responses to the other help threads.

Basically my question is, can i combine

```
r'^input/?$'
```

and

```
r'^input/index.html?$'
```

into this?

```
r'^input(/(index.html?)?)?$'
```

In Django, I get this error:

```
input() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

It only gives the error when it matches correctly, so maybe it's not a regex problem?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would prefer not to combine the two regular expressions. I think that having two url patterns,

```
url(r'^input/?$', input, name="input"),
url(r'^input/index.html?$', input),
```

is more readable than one.

However, if you do want to combine the two, you can use non-capturing parentheses:

```
r'^input(?:/(?:index.html?)?)?$'
```

A quick example might help explain:

```
>>> import re
>>> # first try the regex with capturing parentheses
>>> capturing=r'^input(/(index.html?)?)?$'
>>> # Django passes the two matching strings to the input view, causing the type error
>>> print re.match(capturing, "input/index.html").groups()
('/index.html', 'index.html')
>>> # repeat with non capturing parentheses
>>> non_capturing=r'^input(?:/(?:index.html?)?)?$'
>>> print re.match(non_capturing, "input/index.html").groups()
()
```

See the [Regular Expression Advanced Syntax Reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html) page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this in your `urlpatterns` you don't need to write `?` symbol because everything that comes after that you can parse in your view function. And the request to `/input/index.html?param=2` will be correctly processed with `r'^input/index.html$'` regex. Then in the view function you can obtain parameters like so:

```
def my_view(request):
    param = request.GET.get('param', 'default_value')
```

Find more info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/